# Ultegra CS 6800 Cassette

Tags: cassette, compatibility

I have Dura Ace set up with an Ultegra CS6800 12-28 cassette. I want to alter to 12-32 but the CS6800 isn't available anymore.

Is the R8000 a suitable replacement and what else would I need to complete the upgrade?

Answer (score 4):

Googling 'Shimano CS-6800 cassette' should convince you that Ultegra 6800 cassette are still available, even though that groupset has been superseded by R8000.

Any suitably high-end and light 11 speed Shimano compatible (i.e. Shimano and SRAM) cassette that you can find in you desired spread of sprockets will work.

You will need to check that your rear derailleur has the required *total capacity* (difference in teeth in the cassette + difference in teeth between chainrings), and can handle a 32 tooth large sprocket. If not you will need to swap the derailleur for a compatible one with a longer cage.

Comment: Some cassette ranges are not available for cs6800. But 11-32 is. The problem is with a 30 teeth big one, that size is only for the new ultegra (possibly compatible anyway).